# How to get all custom fields of a particular record type in Netsuite using RESTlet?

Tags: netsuite

I can create a customer, lead, contact using RESTlet. But my code is used by someone who created custom fields with required option. When I try to create a customer, I am getting error by custom required fields.

I want to pass the data for custom required fields too. How to know the all custom fields categorized by required and none required using RESTlet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
var record = nlapiCreateRecord(RECORD_TYPE);
var fields = record.getAllFields();
var requiredFields = [];
fields.forEach(function(fieldName){
 var field = record.getField(fieldName);
 //I am not very sure, its true or T but, below code will work
 if(field.mandatory === true || field.mandatory === 'T'){
   requiredFields.push(field.getName()) //getLabel() for UI label, as getName returns id;
 }
});
```

//requiredFields array is your need.

Comment: What is record prasun?

Comment: getAllFields returns one dimensional array which has only the name of all fields of record type

Comment: `fields.forEach(function(fldName){
var fld = record.getField(fldName);...`

Comment: I tested output line by line. So only got confusion. Code is working very fine prasun. Thanks bknights too.

Comment: i have to create dynamic controls based on standard and custom fields to get a value from user, so i need more details about fields like text box with default value, select (dropdown) with available values in netsuite.

Comment: `record.getField(fieldName);` gives you `nlobjField`, you have all the methods you need i.e. to get available select options, data type, label etc, For a sophisticated eg- check this https://github.com/prasunsultania/mochafornetsuite/blob/master/suite.utils.utils.js [`nsRecord.toJSON()`]

Comment: i got all my requirements from your code except subsidiary. Thank you so much. i want to know some more details . if you free, can you join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96278/netsuite

Answer (score 3):

Actually in this situation I take one of two approaches (or combine them):

The first is to just ignore mandatory fields. You view your code's job is to get information into Netsuite and users will have to be responsible for future updates. You do this by telling Netsuite to ignore mandatory fields when your code saves them:

```
nlapiSubmitRecord(nlobjRecord, doSourcing, ignoreMandatoryFields); //doSourcing and ignoreMandatoryFields are booleans
```

or I add a text area parameter to the restlet where the person configuring the restlet has to enter a list of extra fields you want to do something with (e.g. display in a dialog and make required)